# How to hide status message in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, instant-messaging

How can i hide all status message in `Pidgin` ? for all kinds of accounts , Jabber , MSN etc.

@update:
I actually mean the `short line of message` displayed right after the nick name of contacts , wasn't that called `status message` ? Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It IS a status message. You can hide them in Contacts > Show > [uncheck] Contact details. But take into account that it will also hide the contact images.

Comment: Good , that's what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Open Pidgin, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or go to *Plugins*. Find the *libnotify popups* plugin (which should be enabled by default), click *Configure* on bottom and *Disable All*.

You might want to disable sounds too.

Comment: Would you please see my update , i kinda made a mistake