# How to hide status in pidgin?

Tags: configuration, pidgin, instant-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide status message in Pidgin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70041/how-to-hide-status-message-in-pidgin)

I am using QQ (an IM) in pidgin, I have not found how to hide my status: online, offline, away... Could anyone help?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)